# Deleting sublists from a list

Tags: python, list

I want to delete sublists from a list whose length falls below a certain default value.

Below is a minimal working example. I would like to know if there is a more elegant and shorter way to accomplish this task?

In the example below, there are lists holding ten elements and that I want to keep. Lists that have fewer elements I want to delete.

```
def main():
    # Define lengths of lists
    list_lengths = [10, 6, 9, 10, 4, 2, 0, 10]

    nested_list = list(map(lambda x: list(range(x)), list_lengths))

    print("\nBefore deleting lists that are too short")
    for item in nested_list:
        print(item)
    print()

    # Get max length of all lists
    max_length = max(map(len, nested_list))

    print(f"max_length = {max_length}")

    idx_to_remove = list()
    for i, sublist in enumerate(nested_list):
        if len(sublist) < max_length:
            idx_to_remove.append(i)

    print(f"idx_to_remove = {idx_to_remove}")

    for i, idx in enumerate(idx_to_remove):
        del(nested_list[idx-i])

    print("\nAfter deleting lists that are too short")
    for item in nested_list:
        print(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two-liner :

```py
max_length = max(map(len, nested_list))
nested_list = [i for i in nested_list if not len(i) < max_length]
```

This code has the exact same output than your sample :

```py
def main():
    # Define lengths of lists
    list_lengths = [10, 6, 9, 10, 4, 2, 0, 10]

    nested_list = list(map(lambda x: list(range(x)), list_lengths))

    print("\nBefore deleting lists that are too short")
    for item in nested_list:
        print(item)
    print()

    nested_list = [i for i in nested_list if not len(i) < max(map(len, nested_list))]

    print("\nAfter deleting lists that are too short")
    for item in nested_list:
        print(item)
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. But doesn't this solution have a quadratic time complexity?

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but if `i for i in nested_list` has O(N) complexity and `max(map(len, nested_list))` has O(N) too, it would give a quadratic time complexity. Wouldn't it be enough to calculate the max length beforehands and use a variable to reduce to a linear time complexity ?

Comment: I didnt know you wanted a fast solution, by "shorter" I thought you meant that you wanted less lines of code, hence the one-liner.

Comment: Elegant: Readable, short, and fast ;)

Comment: If you wanted fewer lines of code while still maintaining an O(N) time complexity, you could use the `:=` (walrus) operator, with `nested_list=(max_length := max(map(len, nested_list)),[i for i in nested_list if not len(i) < max_length])[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the filter function:

```
new_nested_list = filter(lambda x: len(x) == max(map(len, nested_list)), nested_list)
```

Comment: Do you need the >=, or will == suffice?

Comment: You're right, I changed it